# O que significa o "carica" na banda "Panda e Os Caricas"

Tags: significado, português-europeu

Meu priminho passou a ouvir um grupo português de música infantil chamado [*"Panda e Os Caricas"*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ylh5F4ol28), e ele me perguntou o que "carica" significa. Mas não faço ideia.

Em Portugal há as [*"caricas"*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/carica) para aquilo que chamamos ["*tampinhas*"](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/tampinha) (i.e., as tampas metálicas de garrafas e latinhas de refrigerantes). Mas qual seria a relação com o grupo infantil?

Por aqui *"tampinha"* também é um sinônimo de *"baixinho"*, se referindo a uma pessoa baixa e, mais estritamente, a um garoto ou criança. Há inclusive uma revista em quadrinhos chamada ["Os Tampinhas"](https://s3.amazonaws.com/moahcapas/tampinhasCapa.jpg). O *"carica"* no nome do grupo teria esse mesmo sentido?

Comment: Nunca ouvi ninguém usar *carica* para significar 'baixinho' ou 'criança', ou outra coisa qualquer que não 'tampa metálica sem rosca'. Há também o jogo da carica, que se joga com caricas. É bem possível que esse nome tenha sido escolhido por qualquer razão privada do pessoal da banda, até mesmo simplesmente por gostarem da sonoridade.

Comment: @Jacinto Essa pregunta já voltou nem sei quantas vezes. Não tem jeito de acabar com isso?

Comment: Parece que a/o Seninha foi passear....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gente, é só olhar na obra maestra: Priberam

Eu sempre dou uma olhada no Priberam:

ca·ri·ca 
(origem obscura)
substantivo feminino
1. Tampa circular, metálica e sem rosca, que veda garrafas de refrigerante ou de cerveja (ex.: a pressão é mantida pela carica da garrafa). (**Equivalente no português do Brasil**: **chapinha**.)Ver imagem

2. [Jogos]  **Jogo infantil em que se usam essas tampas (ex.: jogar à carica**)

[carica](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/carica)

Tudo bem explicadinho. Tudo bonitinho. As músicas são ótimas. :)

Answer (score 1):

A palavra `carica` é uma forma reduzida da palavra `caricatura`, que por sua vez significa `caricaturar`.

Por sua vez, `caricaturar` significa representar (imitar) algo (animal, objeto inanimado, acontecimento etc.) ou alguém (ser humano) de maneira grotesta (ridícula e risível / engraçada).

Consequentemente, um `carica` é uma **pessoa que faz (pratica a) caricatura**, ou seja, é uma pessoa que grotescamente imita / representa algo ou alguém.

No caso da banda "Panda e Os Caricas", tudo nos leva a crer que a intenção do nome seja justamente a de nos evidenciar o fato de que essa banda utiliza o recurso da **paródia** para caricaturar músicas populares, bandas e artistas famosos, "memes" da Internet etc.